# How do I make these sine and cosine functions in Java? (Taylor Series)

Tags: java, bluej

[Taylor series for sine and cosine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX6vN.jpg)I'll post my code here:

```
    public double MiSeno(long n, int t) //n es x, t es en
{
double s = 0, x;
int sig = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < t; i++)
{
    x = Math.pow(n,i) / Factorial(i) * sig;
    sig *= -1;
    s += -x;
}
return s;
 }
```

I know im doing it wrong for now but im getting confused.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with sine series, but from what I can see, how can this be done with code, since `t` should be `Infinity`, which would produce an infinite loop?

Comment: @clabe45 you go until the terms are small.

Comment: Is part of the analysis of the precision of the series.
t is for how many terms it will be analized, t is the exponent

Answer (score 2):

Sine Series has power and factorial moving by two i.e. odd numbers, so your for loop should be:

```
for(int i = 1; i < t; i+=2)
```

Couple of things:

- Make sure you type cast output of Factorial to double to get precise float value.
- Make sure your integer doesn't overflow by factorial calculation too.